# Text between <pre> tag does not retain line breaks when using regex Java

Tags: java, regex

this is my problem.

```
String pattern1 = "<pre.*?>(.+?)</pre>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern1).matcher(html);
if(m.find()) {
    String temp = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

temp does not retain line breaks...it flows as a single line. How to keep the line breaks within temp?

Comment: I believe you want to add `Pattern.DOTALL` to your `compile`.

Comment: Just FYI, your second `if` test redundant.  If `m.find()` passes, you can count on `m.group(1)` being non-null and at least one character long.

Comment: Thanks..will make the change....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using JSoup: html parser

It's very well known that you shouldn't use regex to parse html content, you should use a html parser instead. You can see below how to do it with JSoup:

```
String html = "<p>lorem ipsum</p><pre>Hello World</pre><p>dolor sit amet</p>";
Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
Elements pres = document.select("pre");

for (Element pre : pres) {
    System.out.println(pre.text());
}
```

---

### Pattern.DOTALL: single line compiled flag

However, if you still want to use regex, bear in mind that dot it's a wildcard which doesn't match `\n` unless you specify it intentionally, so you can achieve this in different ways, like using `Pattern.DOTALL`

```
String pattern1 = "<pre.*?>(.+?)</pre>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern1, Pattern.DOTALL).matcher(html);
if(m.find()) {
    String temp = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

### Inline Single line flag:

Or using the `s` flag inline in the regex like this:

```
String pattern1 = "(?s)<pre.*?>(.+?)</pre>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern1).matcher(html);
if(m.find()) {
    String temp = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

### Regex trick

Or you can also use a regex trick that consists of using complementary sets like `[\s\S]`, `[\d\D]`, `[\w\W]`, etc.. like this:

```
String pattern1 = "<pre.*?>([\\s\\S]+?)</pre>";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(pattern1).matcher(html);
if(m.find()) {
    String temp = m.group(1);
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

But as **[nhahtdh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1400768/nhahtdh)** pointed in his comment this trick might impact in the regex engine performance.

Comment: While it is valid, don't use the regex trick `[\s\S]` in Java. It's slower.

Comment: @nhahtdh good pointer, I'll add your comment to the answer. Thanks!

Comment: As mentioned by @Fede I used the Jsoup Parser...There is only one pre tag in the html...yet the newlines don't persist. Maybe there aren't any...but the text within the pre is formatted in the source...http://www.networksolutions.com/whois/results.jsp?domain=google.com

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't parse HTML with regular expressions, but to fix this use the [*dotall*](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-modifiers.html#dotall) modifier ...

```
String pattern1 = "(?s)<pre[^>]*>(.+?)</pre>";
                   ↑↑↑↑
                     |_______ Forces the . to span across newline sequences.
```

Comment: Your question to exactly what you want to do is not clear, the dotall modifier allows you to match across newlines ( retaining them ) ...

Comment: I am trying to get Whois data from a site...I am trying to parse only raw Whois data ...The DOTALL does not seem to match the newlines within the pre text. ex:Domain Name: 1800reservation.comRegistry Domain ID: 313310477_DOMAIN_COM-VRSNRegistrar and so on...

Comment: Well even if it didn't work for me...I learnt something new. 1 upvote.